# Including .clj file in ClojureScript project

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm building a Node.js app in ClojureScript and testing out macros.

**Directory structure:**

```
├── project.clj
└── src
    └── lists
        ├── core.cljs
        └── lib.clj
```

**project.clj:**

```
(defproject lists "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :source-paths ["src/"]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.2"]]
  :cljsbuild {:builds
              [{:source-paths ["src"]
                :compiler {:output-to "target/lists.js"
                          :optimizations :simple
                          :target :nodejs}}]})
```

**src/lists/core.cljs:**

```
(ns lists.core
  (:require [lists.lib :as lib :include-macros true]))

(enable-console-print!)

(lib/defmain [& args]
  (console.log "hello world"))
```

**src/lists/lib.clj:**

```
(ns lists.lib)

(defmacro defmain [& body]
  `(set! *main-cli-fn* (fn ~@body)))
```

When I run `lein cljsbuild once`, I get a huge error traceback containing:

```
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: No such namespace: lists.lib, could not locate lists/lib.cljs or lists/lib.cljc at line 1 src/lists/core.cljs {:file "src/lists/core.cljs", :line 1, :column 1, :tag :cljs/analysis-error}
```

The folder structure is right, and `:source-paths` is present in both the outer
`defproject` call and inner `:cljsbuild :builds` object. What's even weirder is
that sometimes it exits without printing anything. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a dependency on ClojureScript in your `project.clj`.

Comment: Try with `(:require-macros [lists.lib :as lib]))` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

cljsbuild is throwing an exception because it doesn't understand .clj files, it's looking for .cljs or .cljc files in the "src" directory. You have to rename lib.clj to lib.cljc check [using cljc](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Using-cljc) on the clojurescript wiki.